# How to log numeric value for log4j log level instead of string

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

I am using jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final with log4j

> (<version.org.apache.log4j>1.2.16</version.org.apache.log4j>,
> <version.org.apache.logging.log4j>2.11.2</version.org.apache.logging.log4j>);

Currently there are logs in the following format:

> `2022-10-07 16:38:27,819 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock`

But I need the int value of the log level, here INFO (to be processed with fluentbit):

> `2022-10-07 16:38:27,819 X [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock`

Is there a possibility to configure it over the formater pattern?
Currently:

> formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d %-5p [%c] %s%E%n

Or is there another logger, which I could use for it?

Comment: What log manager are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It is org.jboss.logmanager from jboss-logmanager-2.1.10.Final.

Comment: And "org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter"

Comment: There is no option for this in the pattern formatter. You'd have to write a custom formatter.

Comment: Isn't there another fomatter? Or a different Logmanager?

Comment: What container are you running in?

Comment: It is a Docker container with activemq-artemis (version 2.19.1 with jre-11)

Comment: I don't know if that requires the jboss-logmanager or not. However, writing a custom formatter is likely not too bad. Is there a reason you need the int value? I'm just trying to see if I can think of a different option.

Comment: Keep in mind that in 2.27.0 ActiveMQ Artemis will be switching to the SLF4J logging API and using Log4j 2.x as the logging implementation. See [ARTEMIS-4020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4020) for more details.